# UIView transitions with wrong orientation

Tags: xcode, uiview, orientation, storyboard

I have this code (Book1 is a UIViewController Class)

```
Book1 *book = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Book1ID"];    
[UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:book.view duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown completion:nil];
```

The ViewController loads but it the orientation is wrong. It loads in Portrait view but I want it to load in Landscape.

I have the following code in Book1 already but once the view is loaded all autorotation seems to fail.

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;}
```

How can I load this view in Landscape?

Comment: is your storyboard design is in Landscape mode?

Comment: yes but I found that any button I press on the newly instantiated UIView gives me an error: message sent to deallocated instance

Comment: I fixed the deallocated instance error but the page still won't open in Landscape view

Comment: that's why because your whole design is in Portrait mode and the method `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` will called when the orientation of device is changed after the view is loaded so you have to design the view in landscap mode to launch it in landscap mode or you have to restrict your parent/root view to landscap mode only

Comment: Awesome, how do I restrict it to landscape? I've only selected the landscape options in my settings,set my storyboards to landscape and added the should rotate delegate to my classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found the problem with my previous methods but I found another way to do it.

This is how:

```
book = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Book1ID"];
book.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:book animated:YES completion:^(void){}];
```

Special thanks to Aalok Parikh for all your help

Answer (score 0):

So Do the things like the below:

**First**

[image: Supported Device Orientations]

Just Select those two orientations as supported device orientations :)

**Second**

[image: plist file key entry]

Now Add the key **The Last one in image** `Initial interface orientation` and the value you want either of two landscape values from the list

**Third**

Now add the below function to all your controller's .m file

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

**Forth**

Just build and run your project :)

That's it now your application is restricted to the landscape mode only

Happy Codding:)

Comment: Firstly thanks for all your help and patience.
I followed those instructions to the letter but the transition still shows Portrait. The auto rotation (e.g. me lifting the ipad up and turning it) also has no effect. It's like the class is instantiated only partially and the extra stuff, like delegates etc., fails

Comment: `transition still shows portait` means? still the view at launch is in portrait mode? Is it true? But it works for me fine.

Comment: no the view at launch is in landscape. It's when I try to load a second view programaticly (as in the first block of code I posted) that the second view shows in Portrait and auto rotation doesn't work

Comment: so for that you must use the **Third** step in the second views .m file that must be designed in landscap mode in xib or storyboard and the problem will be solved as per my knowledge

Comment: yeah I already did that. But thanks for your help anyway I really appreciate it

Comment: so problem is not solved yet? right? sorry for that i will try to find some other workaround let you know if i found any thing ok :)

Comment: Nope Problem not solved. Thank you. Will it help if I post more code and try to explain my situation better? if so where can I post it or should I just edit this post? Sorry I'm really new to stackoverflow

Comment: ok so you have to do is just add one line `book.frame = CGRect(0,0,width,height)`before the `UIView transitionFrom:...` line i think this will solve your problem but you have to design your view in landscape size in storyboard for this to work

Comment: damn, no luck. This is what I did: `book.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, book.view.frame.size.width, book.view.frame.size.height);`

Comment: does it is in landscape mode ie designed for landscap view on storyboard? if yes then try to give absolute values like 1024 for width and 748 for height

Comment: yes it is designed for landscape in storyboard. ok I put in the absolute values. the view is still in portrait but it seems to have shifted up. So now theres a big black area on the left and next to it the view starts still in portrait